# Start and Stop Tomcat service using Ant

Tags: tomcat, ant

I need to start Tomcat application running as a service (application) in windows machine with an Ant buildfile. I am able to do the same with available batch file to start up and shutdown. But, now I want to make this happen without batch file.

> Note: Now tomcat is running as application service

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

1. First Create a macro named service:

   ```
   <macrodef name="service">
   <attribute name="service" />
   <attribute name="action" />
   <sequential>
       <exec executable="cmd.exe">
           <arg line="/c net @{action} '@{service}'" />
       </exec>
   </sequential>
   ```
2. Now create a task that uses the service macro:

   ```
   <property name="servicename" value="myWindowsServiceName" />
   <target name="start">           
      <service action="start" service="${servicename}" />
   </target>
   <target name="stop">
       <service action="stop" service="${servicename}" />
   <exec dir="." executable="cmd.exe">
       <arg line ="/c taskkill /f /fi 'services eq ${servicename}' " />
   </exec>
       <sleep seconds="5" />
   </target>
   <target name="restart" depends="stop,start" />
   ```