# ANT check and stop the services by port number used

Tags: ant

I want to check whether any services is running on port 8081, if found running I want to stop the service in linux machine with the ANT build tool

Comment: Why use a build tool for that... do you use a coffee machine to boil your potatoes? The killing itself is already covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826211/ant-built-to-start-stop-tomcat-service), and you have neither commented nor accepted the answer there.

Comment: It's the logic condition for my application to run. I am not stating about tomcat execution. Its about execution of jar file in certain port number. This needs to happen before deployment of my application each time. So, I have integrated this to my CI setup and ANT