# What is the different between Tomcat started by Window."Services" and By executing startup.bat on cmd

Tags: tomcat, ant, startup, shutdown

For startup.bat , it only start localhost:8080 ,

For Window.Service , it start all hosts and port i specified on Server.xml

How can i use Ant to start Window.Service tomcat xxxxxx

Comment: What is the need to start it via Ant? If it is a windows service and set to automatic then it will startup automatically at machine restart. In case of failure you don't have to bring back the service as it is set to auto start mode.

Comment: See [ANT built to start & stop tomcat service](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32839258/1078068) for a possible solution.

Comment: basically, i am working on Ant Script for deploying my workspace code to tomcat server. I want my script handle stop and start server via window.service ( in this case, I can see whether the server is up/down on the Services window)